# Does every single javascript file in a Rails app need .on('page:change', initialize)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Let's say I have a rails application that is "restful."  Lets say I have a bunch of resources: a `blog`, a `book`, a `user`, a `comment` etc.

Each of these resources will have their corresponding javascript file: `blogs.js`, `books.js`, `users.js`, `comments.js`, etc.

I understand that, in order to be compatible with turbo links, each of these files needs to have something like the following:

```
function initialize(){
    ...
}
$(document).on('page:change', initialize);
```

As I understand it, I have to do this for *every single js file*.  Is this accurate?  If it is accurate, is there a way that I can do this just *once* so that all javascript files know to not load in their code until the DOM (with turbo links enabled) is ready for the javascript code?  It seems to be breaking the "Don't repeat yourself" rule.

Or, if I am incorrect in how I think it needs to be done, please let me know my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand it, I have to do this for every single js file

Yes, you are right, no minimal work-around for that.

But, you can use [**jQuery Turbolinks**](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem :

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

*application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

... and that's it!

And make sure **not to do** this in your code after using `jQuery Turbolinks`:

```
/* BAD: don't bind 'document' events while inside $()! */
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() { ... })
});
```

Instead **Do** this:

```
/* Good: events are bound outside a $() wrapper. */
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() { ... })
```